# Automatically responding yes to forfiles

Tags: windows, command-line, script, batch

I'm looking to automatically delete files older than 7 days old with `forfiles`.

The code below works when I do it manually and respond yes to deleting the files. How can I incorporate the yes into this?

This is the output:

```
E:\>forfiles -p "H:\SHARED\Scans" -s -m *.* -d -7 -c "cmd /c del @path"
Could Not Find H:\SHARED\Scans\.DS_Store
H:\SHARED\Scans\XXX\DOC006.XSM\*, Are you sure (Y/N)?
```

Comment: what happens when you try  echo y |  before it?

Comment: Note that contrary to what MS docs say, `/m *.*` in `forfiles` does not match all files. It will only match files whose names have an extension. If you want to match *all* files, you need `/m *`. Or just omit `/m` entirely, since `/m *` is the default.

Answer (score 10):

You could try adding in a /Q /S, though be aware that this may not in fact do what you really want it to:

```
/Q Quiet mode, do not ask if ok to delete on global wildcard
/S Delete specified files from all subdirectories

E:\forfiles -p "H:\SHARED\Scans" -s -m . -d -7 -c "cmd /c del /Q /S @path"
```

You are probably better off either using CSCRIPT (with your choice of VBScript or JScript) or PowerShell. Check out this answer from StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575493/how-to-delete-empty-subfolders-with-powershell

Here is some vbscript to accomplish a similar task:

```
Dim fso, folder, folders
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set parent = fso.GetFolder("H:\SHARED\Scans")
Set folders = parent.SubFolders

' delete any folder older than 7 days
For Each folder in folders
    If Abs(DateDiff("d",Date, folder.DateCreated)) > 7 Then
        folder.Delete(True) 'force delete
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Might want to try `H:\SHARED\Scans\ ` seems the `.DS_STORE` is getting appended to the current folder @PHLiGHT

Answer (score 0):

This example removes all files in the folder "G:\db_bk_copies" older than 3 days without asking the users to confirm deletion (Are you sure (Y/N)?):

`forfiles -p "G:\db_bk_copies" -s -m * /D -3 /C "cmd /c del /a-s @path"`

Answer (score -1):

Verify that the files are not Hidden or system files.

If System try:

```
forfiles -p "H:\SHARED\Scans" -s -m *.* -d -7 -c "cmd /c del /a-s @path"
```

If Hidden Try:

```
forfiles -p "H:\SHARED\Scans" -s -m *.* -d -7 -c "cmd /c del /a-h @path"
```

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.